# Powershell qutoas

Tags: windows, powershell, quota

> I want to add a quotas to a specific user folder (the folder name is the the username ) so I create a new folder with the username($NomUtilisateur) but after I want to add a quotas with fileServerRessourceManager.

I have this error :The error is: Set-FsrmQuota : 0x80045301, C:\Users\Administrateur.WIN-FIGS37ME7FE\desktop\Script.ps1:125 : 3 + Set-FsrmQuota -Path $path -Description "limit usage to 0.1 GB" -Si ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (MSFT_FSRMQuota:Root/Microsoft/.../MSFT _FSRMQuota) [Set-FsrmQuota], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80045301,Set-FsrmQuota –

```
if (DossierUser($vrai=0)) {
  New-Item -Path "U:\LeProgramme\" -Name "$NomUtilisateur" -ItemType "directory"
  Set-FsrmQuota -Path "U:\LeProgramme\$NomUtilisateur" -Description "limit usage to 0.1 GB" -Size 0.1GB
}


else {
  New-Item -Path "V:\LeProgramme\" -Name "$NomUtilisateur" -ItemType "directory"
  Set-FsrmQuota -Path "V:\LeProgramme\$NomUtilisateur" -Description "limit usage to 0.1 GB" -Size 0.1GB
}
```

Comment: [1] so ... what is your Question? ///// [2] where is `DossierUser($vrai=0)` defined?

Comment: i Create a files with New-Item -Path "U:\LeProgramme\" -Name "$NomUtilisateur" -ItemType "directory" and i want to add a quotas to this file

Comment: so your Question is how to use the `Set-FsrmQuota` cmdlet? what does not work when you try to use it? what errors do you get? ///// also, PLEASE ... remove any code that does not directly involve your Question.

Comment: The error is: Set-FsrmQuota : 0x80045301,  C:\Users\Administrateur.WIN-FIGS37ME7FE\desktop\Script.ps1:125 : 3
+   Set-FsrmQuota -Path $path  -Description "limit usage to 0.1 GB" -Si ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_FSRMQuota:Root/Microsoft/.../MSFT 
   _FSRMQuota) [Set-FsrmQuota], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80045301,Set-FsrmQuota

Comment: good! now ... add that info to your Question & wrap it in code formatting so that others can find & read it. [*grin*]

Comment: `-Size` should be a UInt64 number. `0.1GB` amounts to `107374182.4` and is of type `Double`

Comment: Also, error `0x80045301` usually means _The requested object was not found_, but you didn't show us the whole error message unfortunately. Didn't you forget a `$` on variable `DossierUser` and are you sure `$NomUtilisateur` has some value?

Comment: Use `New-FsrmQuota` (instead of `Set-`)